# get no of records returned by query in jscript function

Tags: javascript, jscript, javascript-databinding

How I can get no of records returned by my query executed with in j script function? I am trying it as following but not getting where I am doing wrong.

```
function getExecutableSteps() 
{

    var pad ="C:\\Automation\\Workspace\\Input\\Automation.accdb";
    var cn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
    var strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + pad;
    cn.Open(strConn);
    var cm = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Command");
    cm.ActiveConnection = cn;
    cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TestSteps where TestStepNo='TSU1_TC1_TST1'";
    var rs = cm.Execute(); 
    var TotalnoofRecords = rs.row.count;
    Log.Message(TotalnoofRecords)
}
```

Comment: I think more info is needed. Are you getting errors? (If so, what?). Try putting some console.log s in your function, to log variables and the progress of execution. Then you will know when and where your assumptions about the code fails.

Comment: JavaScript or JScript?

Comment: @DNKROZ I am using J script

Comment: @jonahe I am getting error as 'row.count' is null or not an object.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/recordset-object-properties-methods-and-events), the Recordset object has no row property. Read about the (availability of the) [Recordcount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/recordcount-property-ado) property to see why a test of .[EOF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/bof-eof-properties-ado) is the way to go.